# Can I mount a large projector screen to metal studs with just screws?

Tags: walls, mounting, drywall-anchor

What is the best and easiest way to mount my new projector screen to the wall?  I was thinking of snap toggles not in the studs, but then someone said I should try to use snap toggles in the metal studs which seems like overkill. The screen is 170 inch diagonal and estimated to weigh about 66 pounds.  There are two mounting brackets that each take two screws. Based on the mounting bracket screw locations, I couldn't get both into a stud even if I wanted to. Am I better to just use togglers away from the studs?

[In this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/N6jujf4hgaE?si=kaeYE7wBdWcirqJZ&t=120) <sub>queued to start at 2:00</sub> (at 2:09) you can see the bracket in the instruction manual and the actual bracket above the manual. They also show them on the wall at the end of the video around 11:05

Comment: For something like this I suspect that your instruction manual has specific mounting directions. Without specific geometry, I'm uncomfortable offering anything. Is the TV hanging far off the wall? Or is it tight to the wall? Is this drywall? 3/8"? 5/8"? Is the mounting bracket wide enough to bore custom holes on top of studs?

Comment: No time to search for a duplicate, but I'm sure they are out there. TL;DR either figure out how to mount in the studs (metal a little different from wood, but the idea is the same) or mount plywood to the studs and screen to plywood.

Comment: @popham OP's not mounting a _TV_ he's mounting a _projector screen_. I'd be _very_ impressed by a 170" TV period not to mention a 170" TV that only weighs 66 lbs.

Comment: How about giving us a picture of the mounting brackets or the brand/model of the screen or, even better, a link to the installation instructions. You mention in a comment on an answer that the mounting holes are 2" apart, but I can't envision how that works to hold up a 170" screen...

Comment: @FreeMan, I was impressed by that 66#. Amazing!

Comment: https://youtu.be/N6jujf4hgaE?si=kaeYE7wBdWcirqJZ  At 2:09 you can see the bracket in the instruction manual and the actual bracket above the manual.  They also show them on the wall at the end of the video around 11:05

Comment: Any thoughts about brackets

Answer (score 5):

Mount to the studs; plasterboard isn't really intended to take that much weight, toggle bolts or not. Screws directly into the studs will do fine. Predrill with a bit no larger than the base of the screw threads, or use self-drilling metal screws.

Steel stud spacing should be a multiple of 2", assuming the US. If you're at the upper range of 24" that might be a problem for a bracket intended for 16" studs. In that case, stud on one side and whatever you can do on the other is still your strongest option. Or you could do the backing-board routine, mount thin wood between the studs, paint to match either the wall or the bracket or the set,  mount the set centered on that.

Comment: Yes, but The bracket has screw holes like 2 inches apart or something like that, I won't hit the stud in both places.  I'd prefer to do that, nice and easy and much less damage to the walls.

Comment: @robl45 A) no more or less damage to the wall going into a toggle vs a screw hole - just a bigger hole but future repair is the same, B) sometimes you just have to work with what you're given, C) with a steel stud, a toggle might be your best bet, even if you do hit a stud.

Answer (score 1):

With just the two small brackets provided I would not hang 66 pounds on drywall.

You *could* hang a big 66 pound screen on drywall.  Since it's not a TV and people won't be touching it all the time, it can be done safely.  But I don't think doing it with just two of those small brackets would be sufficient.  And since you have the flexibility to position them and use studs, it makes no sense to get too creative with this.

Position each bracket so one of the holes is centered over a stud.  Use a sheet metal screw there.  Watch videos and search this site for how to properly size and use sheet metal screws.   For the other hole in each bracket use a self-drilling drywall anchor.  Also watch videos on how to properly install those.  When done properly they can hold much more than 17 pounds (66/4), but in your case the studs will do most of the work anyway. You don't need toggle anchors.